# Deleting Access Control List in Cisco Router

Tags: router, acl

Let's say I have a access-list 1 with 5 permits.
And I would like to delete the third permit listing.
I know that I can simply do "no 30"

However, can I confirm that I can 
`no access-list 1 permit host 192.168.1.1` command in global configuration mode. Or `no access-list 1` global configuration command, and then re-enter the other 4 access-list?

Comment: Check out "ip access list expanded ..." - this will allow you to delete individual lines as well as insert new ones and re-sequence.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer below is helpful and correct?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you know how to remove a single line from the ACL (using `no sequence_number` form), I would focus on your two commands:

- `no access-list 1 permit host 192.168.1.1` command indeed deletes your ENTIRE ACL, thus NEVER use this kind of command.
- `no access-list 1` command obviously deletes your ENTIRE ACL, you then re-apply other 4 lines, thus it is technically correct, but remember to remove the ACL from an interface before removing or adding the ACL.

And always remember to remove the ACL from an interface before removing or adding the ACL.

Comment: I have doubts on "no access-list 1 permit host 192.168.1.1 command indeed deletes your ENTIRE ACL, thus NEVER use this kind of command." Do remember this is global configuration mode...and shouldnt only that particular line belonging to list 1 gets deleted???????

Comment: @user2947950 It will delete the whole `access-list 1`, please read [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html) for further information. To clear your doubts, the best way is to give it a try on GNS3 or on a redundant/backup/non-production router. And as I said before, always remove the ACL from an interface before removing or adding the ACL.